# Why is my anki importing a word twice?

Tags: anki

I have imported a csv file as follows into my anki.

```
吧,,ba5
毕,,bi4
秉,,bing3
餐,,can1
单,,dan1
果,,guo3
洁,,jie2
结,,jie2
就,,jiu4
刘,,liu2
品,,pin3
其,,qi2
请,,qing3
如,,ru2
他,,ta1
甜,,tian2
完,,wan2
些,,xie1
用,,yong4
账,,zhang4
这,,zhe4
账单,bill,zhang4dan1
甜品,dessert,tian2pin3
完毕,finished,wan2bi4
如果,if,ru2guo3
用餐,meal,yong4can1
其他,other,qi2ta1
刘秉洁,Serena,liu2bing3jie2
就这些,that's it,jiu4zhe4xie1
请结账吧,please check out,qing3jie2zhang4ba5
```

However when I go to browse the deck in Anki the cards appear twice. What am I doing wrong?

Also notice the huge increment in card number. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your note type contains 2 cards.

Go on `Tools -> Manage note types`, choose the note type you are using and click on `Cards...` to see what are *Card 1* and *Card 2*.

The drop-down list on the top will show you the available cards for  this note type and you'll have the preview on the right side of the screen.

Typically, *Card 1* can be *Chinese to English* and *Card 2* would be *English to Chinese*.